# python 2.7 unicode shows different result between local and server

Tags: python, unicode

I entered `"久保充明"` in both my local computer and server,

1) First Question
local - python2.7.10 - Korean computer

```
>>> a = "久保充明"
>>> a
'\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5'
```

server - python2.7.6 - (Japanese Server?)

```
>>> a = "久保充明"
>>> a
'\xe4\xb9\x85\xe4\xbf\x9d\xe5\x85\x85\xe6\x98\x8e'
```

both are showing different result...

Are there anybody tell why the results different??
Maybe the OS language is different??

2) Second Question
why the Python show this?

```
'\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5' (<- what is this??)
```

instead of this?

```
"久保充明"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 2 and you're writing characters in your local encoding on your local computer; which it is, I have no idea; it is not UTF-8, nor GB2312, 18030, Big5 or Shift-JIS:

```
>>> print('\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5'.decode('GB2312'))
矽芰貊佶
>>> print('\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5'.decode('GB18030'))
矽芰貊佶
>>> print('\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5'.decode('Big5'))
朏僋蘜晱
>>> print('\xce\xf9\xdc\xc1\xf5\xf6\xd9\xa5'.decode('Shift-jis'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: illegal multibyte sequence
```

On server, you're using UTF-8.

**You should be using UTF-8/Unicode always; and actually Python 3 specifies that UTF-8 is the source code encoding by default.** Furthermore start your source files with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and use `u''` unicode strings. If possible, consider switching to Python 3; it would also probably solve the issues with question 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. The two operating system's character set doesnot set samely so their output is different.
2. the result is the chinese character's coding， if you set encoding before you print a,you will get what you want.

write in file test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = "久保充明"
print(a)
```